# Swift - Push Notification JSON format

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Please let me ask about Push Notification issue here.

Our server sent out the data in JSON format like this

```
{
"notification":

    {
    "body”:”Test Push Notification (42)”,
    "node":"1233837”,
    "content-available":"1"
    },
    "priority":"high"

}
```

The process of sending out push notification to our app is

- We sent out notification from our sever to GCM
- From GCM, sending out to APNS.

But when we receive push notification in our app, the format is totally changed (as shown in attached image).

[image]

If you face with this kinda issue before, could you share with how to solve it, please?

Or is there any way to change in GCM to get normal JSON format?

Comment: try adding more key to the payload like `"data":{ "key" : "value" }` and check the output

Comment: Can't we use current format?

Comment: current format is fine. apple expect the notification payload to have aps key with alert to show the Alert at home screen. for custom data -- try using custom keys. this must be explained better in docs i think.

Comment: We use "aps" as a key before, but I don't know why with key named "aps", our sever cannot send out notification. Only with key named "notication", I receive push notification in our app. How weird! :(

Answer (score 1):

Try next format to send notification to GCM:

```
{ "notification": { "body”:”Test Push Notification (42)”, "node":"1233837” }, "priority":10, "content-available":true }
```

From APNS you app get some like this

```
{
  aps:{
       alert:{
                   *bla bla bla*
        }, 
        *bla bla bla*
 }}
```

Just parse it in `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer